# Построить вектор заданной длины из заданной точки в определенном направлении

Tags: математика, вектор

[image: Схема задачи]

Наведите, пожалуйста, на правильный ход мыслей по поводу задачи (см. рисунок):
- Есть камера Cam, она вращается вокруг центра координат.
- Есть маркер Marker. Его координаты известны, как и координаты камеры. Он статичен.

Нужно: найти точку на окружности вокруг маркера, которая лежала бы на отрезке, проведенном от маркера до камеры (или наоборот).
Проще говоря, мне нужны координаты вектора, длиной в радиус окружности, построенного из маркера в сторону камеры.

Сам пока додумался только до вычитания векторов, чтобы получить вектор из камеры в маркер. Далее - только метод тыка, пока ни к чему хорошему не приведший.

По возможности, хочется решить задачу без матриц и тригонометрии, из соображений производительности.

Comment: у вас камера движется по окружности и окружность вокруг маркера - они как-то связаны?

Comment: Нет, не связаны. Окружность вокруг маркера условная - чтобы было понятно, что вектор, смотрящий в сторону камеры, должен быть заданной постоянной длины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-t1)^2

x3 = x1 + R/L * (x2 - x1)

аналогично y3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо вам огромное! R/L*(x2-x1) - это вообще формула века:) Сам бы ни за что не додумался.

Comment: Куда ж оно денется - это же геометрия за 3 класс :) Удачи!

Comment: ничего страшного :) обращайтесь, если что. Удачи!